# Leave my app on device - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android dev and i'm having a stupid problem with Android Studio. I'm running my app on my phone, which is working pretty good, but once I stop the app I can't restart it immediatly from my phone, I got to re-run the app on Android Studio (it says the app is not install).

I would like to know if it was possible to install my app once for all? I would like to be able to restart my app even if my phone is not connected to my PC through USB.

Thanks for your help !

Edit : Adding logcat of the app execution (only errors)

[image: Logcat of my app]

I'm pretty much ignoring them most of the time because my app is running as expected, but maybe?

Edit2 : Allright bug is fix, I just had to desinstall and re-run my app and i can now restart it from my phone without Android Studio. Thanks for the help people !

Comment: That should be possible, I do this all the time. How do you stop it? Through Android Studio or just on your phone?

Comment: I forget to say that Gradle was in "Make" mode for deployment. @Cherry-wave : It's saying it's not install in both case, if i stop it through Android studio or through my phone.

Comment: It's really strange. Could you please attach a log from a debugger?

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure if this is what you're asking but here are the errors I got from my logcat

Comment: So when you open it from the launcher browser, it doesn't do anything?

Comment: It does, the app is starting, running as expected. Once i close it, though Android Studio or manually on my phone, if i restart it, it says "The application is not install". If I want to re-run it, I got to do it from Android Studio once again :/.

Comment: That is a weird issue.  One thing I'd like to see is if you can install the app through ADB and run it normally like that.  You should be able to get the .apk from "{app-folder}/build/outputs/".  Then install it through "adb install {apk-path}".

Comment: Hmm, actually i don't have anything named output in my build folder, only "generated" and "intermediates", I guess you pointed out something